# Django-Configurations is causing my STATIC_URL to be invalid

Tags: python, django

I have a django(1.6.5) project and I am using the [django-configurations(0.8)](https://github.com/jezdez/django-configurations) package and I am trying to set the STATIC_URL in the settings.py file with an environment variable by doing:

```
from configurations import Configuration, values
BUCKET_NAME = values.SecretValue()
STATIC_URL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/%s/' % BUCKET_NAME
```

But the STATIC_URL is set to:

```
'https://s3.amazonaws.com/<Value default:None>'
```

which is not valid or intended. I have the correct environment variable set too: DJANGO_BUCKET_NAME='thekey'

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You may find interesting this [project template](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) that uses that libraries and is well configured.

Comment: I did use that cookie cutter with a slight variation, but my variation should not affect the STATIC_URL

Comment: I looked at issues with the django cookie cutter and found this solution: https://github.com/burhan/cookiecutter-django/commit/c8ee217dd72ec29ccea4f683d83ca7438247461c

Comment: So answer the question yourself and mark it as resolved, other users may find it interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at issues with the django cookie cutter and found this solution:

https://github.com/burhan/cookiecutter-django/commit/c8ee217dd72ec29ccea4f683d83ca7438247461c

Which told me to switch:

```
STATIC_URL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/%s/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
```

to:

```
STATIC_URL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/%s/' % (AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME.setup('DJANGO_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME'),)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `__repr__` method for `Value` in django-configurations.
They already fixed this issue but didn't update the pckage version, so pypy still reference the buggy version.

[v-0.8](https://github.com/jezdez/django-configurations/blob/0.8/configurations/values.py) vs [updated version](https://github.com/jezdez/django-configurations/blob/master/configurations/values.py)

A workaround is to set your `STATIC_URL` to:

```
'https://s3.amazonaws.com/%s/' % (AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME.setup('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME'),)
```

Source: https://github.com/burhan/cookiecutter-django/commit/c8ee217dd72ec29ccea4f683d83ca7438247461c

Comment: This throws `ValueError: Secret value 'DJANGO_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME' is not set`