# More idiomatic way of retrieving values in django-configuration

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am using django-configurations (version 0.8) in my django project. I have something like this in my configuration settings.

```
class MyConfiguration(Configuration):
    AWS_STATIC_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = values.SecretValue()
    AWS_MEDIA_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = values.SecretValue()
    MEDIA_URL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/%s/' % AWS_MEDIA_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
    STATIC_URL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/%s/' % AWS_STATIC_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
```

Later on when I try to access the value of MEDIA_URL and STATIC_URL, I retrieve their values using the following code:

```
import config
print config.MEDIA_URL
print config.STATIC_URL
```

I see that it prints

```
<Value default: None>/
```

I figured that this is because when the assignment to MEDIA_URL and STATIC_URL takes place in MyConfiguration, the value of AWS_STATIC_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME and AWS_MEDIA_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME (that comes from values.SecretValue())  is not available yet. I have fixed this by changing the first two lines to below:

```
import os
AWS_STATIC_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['DJANGO_AWS_STATIC_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME'] 
AWS_MEDIA_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['DJANGO_AWS_MEDIA_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME']
```

But, I am wondering if there is a better way to set the values of MEDIA_URL and STATIC_URL i.e. more idiomatic usage of django-configuration.

Regards,

SN

Answer (score 0):

What about retrieving it like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
print settings.MEDIA_URL
print settings.STATIC_URL
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and it looks like it's an issue with the PyPi version of `Django-Configurations`. I found a solution at [Django-Configurations is causing my STATIC_URL to be invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017859/django-configurations-is-causing-my-static-url-to-be-invalid/25147011).

You should be able to pull the value within the `SecretValue` using the following syntax:

```
STATIC_URL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/%s/' % (AWS_STATIC_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME.setup('DJANGO_AWS_STATIC_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME'),)
```

The same approach could be used with the `MEDIA_URL` configuration setting.